# Vue lifecycle hooks and getters with vuex and es6

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex, arrow-functions

I've been using Vue for a while now no problems, using "let self: any = this;" often.  Not the best practice, but it works.

Or rather it did.  I created a new project yesterday, and now it doesn't like that.  @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias.
Ok fine, I should probably stop doing that anyways.  But problem now is, how?

```
<template>
  ...
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  ...
  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
  ...
@Component({
  ...
  methods: {
    ...mapGetters(["getLoading"]),
    ...mapActions(["fetchIsAllowed"])
  }
  ...
export default class App extends Vue {
  get isLoading() {
    let self: any = this;
    return self.getLoading();
  }
  mounted(){
   let self: any = this;
    self.fetchIsAllowed();
  }
}
</script>
```

I've tried a few things, but can't get anything to work.

```
get loading() {
  return this.getLoading();
}
mounted(){
 this.fetchIsAllowed();
}
```

getLoading and fetchIsAllowed doen't not exist on type 'App'

```
get isLoading = () => {
  return this.getLoading();
}
mounted = () => {
  this.fetchIsAllowed();
}
```

Same thing.  getLoading and fetchIsAllowed doen't not exist on type 'App'

```
get isLoading(() => {
  return this.getLoading();
})
mounted(() => {
  this.fetchIsAllowed();
})
```

Parameter declaration expected for both.

Comment: `mapGetters` should be in `computed`, not `methods`

Comment: Out of topic but heavy wondering since I see it often: why do people even `self = this` ? Does it have some benefits ?

Comment: @kissu It's unnecessary in this code, but usually people will do this to keep a reference to the original `this` for use within a callback function (even though that function can use `bind` or fat arrow syntax to preserve `this`).